# configuration file to output dir when testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, file

when I execute the tests from Visual studio 2010, the app.config used in the test is not being copied to the folder TestResults/Out.
Icant set the Deployment test settings because there are more than one test project that have the same filename

What can i do to solve this? is there any other way to achieve the content file deployment when running tests?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's relative simple use a custom configuration file in your tests.
For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for RelatorioTest
/// </summary>
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("dependency.config")] <- put here your configuration file path.
public class RelatorioTest
{
   ...
}
```